# for each loop, every item in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops, foreach, haml

I've passed a field from my database, into my controller, so `@download` has a value of `/link1, /link2, link3` I need to display all three links in my view. I've tried the following code:

```
%ul.pdf
  - ["#{@download}"]. each do|li|
    %li= link_to "title", "#{ li }"
```

but this just shows one hyperlink with the value of all three links in one. Is there any way i can get it to split at each comma or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can split at the comma *(this accounts for whitespace following the comma too)*.

```
@download.split(/,\s+/)
```

or, as a whole

```
%ul.pdf
  - @download.split(/,\s+/).each do|li|
    %li= link_to "title", "#{ li }"
```

though you might consider doing the `split` in the controller on `@download` depending on the context.